# Access Denied when copying a file to another user drive Graph API (Postman)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I want to copy a file from my drive to another user drive (user created from Azure -> Users).

Here my request : `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{{item-id}}/copy`
with body :

```
{   
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!lPHrO2WBhUq921ctUxfmYoHU7F32SMZGtvttvkkGUSdqTn52_ou6SrU2ugSu7EHV",
        "id": "01AIV4ADN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
    },
    "name": "excel(copy).xlsx" 
}
```

And the response is :

```
"error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied",
}
```

The Postman API permissions (with Microsoft Azure) that I have are :
Files.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All (fort Delegated and Application)

If I change driveId and id with my drive, it works, but another drive I got "accesDenied"
Someone can help me ? Thanks